# Unable to achieve a specific format of JSON

Tags: python, json

I need my python file to return a json output in the format.

```
{

"1": ["1503", "22939", "0", "0.0", "T"],

"2": ["850", "4895", "4", "1.647058823529412", "T"],

"3": ["337", "2748", "2", "2.3738872403560833", "T"],

"4": ["260", "2041", "2", "3.076923076923077", "T"]

}
```

The best  I could get is individual items of output like this

```
{"1": ["1503", "22939", "0", "0.0", "T"]}

{"2": ["850", "4895", "4", "1.647058823529412", "T"]}

{"3": ["337", "2748", "2", "2.3738872403560833", "T"]}

{"4": ["260", "2041", "2", "3.076923076923077", "T"]}
```

My code reads from a CSV file and generates a Json.

```
    # in an iterative for loop

    # Empty variable

    data = {}

    #lineCount is an incremental index , content List is a populated List

    data[lineCount] =contentList

    # Converting to a json format

    json_data = json.dumps(data)

    print(json_data)
```

I tried in different ways but unable to generate my intended format, any help is appreciated.

Comment: you have probably created a list of dicts, instead of a single dict. But your code is incomplete so we cannot be sure

Comment: yes , there are lot of lines , but i just took out the main part to avoid confusion. Let my edit and add a few more lines

Comment: ... and you failed....

Comment: To help you we need some of your data and the full code you are using. (A minimal example)

Comment: Aren't the numbered keys redundant? You can have a list of lists

Comment: Nope , they are not redundant, the variable linecount is the numbered key which gets incremented everytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
data = {}

#lineCount is an incremental index , content List is a populated List

data[lineCount] =contentList

# Converting to a json format

json_data = json.dumps(data)
```

doing that in a loop creates a new dictionary each time, which explains the list of 1-item dictionaries.

Initialize your dict only once:

```
data = {}
```

then loop and populate it

```
for lineCount in some_iterable:
    ...
    data[lineCount] = contentList
```

then at the end of the loop, dump it

```
json_data = json.dumps(data)
```